# Calling vba function(with parameters) from vbscript and show the result

Tags: vba, vbscript, arguments

I have the following vba function ( in a module in Excel file)

```
Public Function validate_fncname(strFncname As String) As Boolean
.
.
.
validate_fncname  = True
End Function
```

and I wrote the following vbscript to call it :

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook =  objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\uidu8611\Desktop\CAM0500040F10_SW_Quality_Assurance_Report_Template(new_version).xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

Dim str
str ="hello"

Dim validate_fncname 

 validate_fncname =  objExcel.Application.Run("'C:\Users\uidu8611\Desktop\CAM0500040F10_SW_Quality_Assurance_Report_Template(new_version).xlsm'!validate_fncname", str)

Wscript.Echo validate_fncname
```

however when I run the script, it gives me type mismatch error for the line:

```
objExcel.Application.Run("'C:\Users\uidu8611\Desktop\CAM0500040F10_SW_Quality_Assurance_Report_Template(new_version).xlsm'!validate_fncname", str)
```

Despite the fact that the type is correct (String)

furthermore if I change it to :

```
objExcel.Application.Run("'C:\Users\uidu8611\Desktop\CAM0500040F10_SW_Quality_Assurance_Report_Template(new_version).xlsm'!validate_fncname(5)")
```

It doesn't give me an error, although 5 is integer!

Where is my mistake please?

Comment: Does your second version actually return a value? It doesn't look like it would work at all, since that's not how you pass arguments using `run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have your `validate_fncname` method, which looks fine (except setting the return value to `True` should probably be done in an `if then` statement to avoid setting everything to `True`).

When calling this function, you should just be able to do the following:

```
Dim validateResult As Boolean
Dim str as String
str = "hello"
validateResult = validate_fncname(str)
Debug.Print validateResult
```

Answer (score 2):

I played with this for a while and came up with the same error.
In my case I was just trying to pass a string back and forth.

Then I looked up the dim statement for VBScript and it says "All VBScript variables are variants" so I changed the function on the spreadsheet to as Variant and that worked for me.  Hope this helps others that come across this thread.