# Pass parameter from VbScript to vba function

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I want to call a vba function from vbscript which has a parameter, I Know how to call a parameterized sub but having issue with function

Here is what I have tried, I tried the code here   [Calling vba function(with parameters) from vbscript and show the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232615/calling-vba-functionwith-parameters-from-vbscript-and-show-the-result)   , but this also didn't work, it gave an error as expected end of statement

```
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = xlObj.Workbooks.Open("E:\Headers.xlsm")

xlObj.Application.Visible = False
xlObj.Workbooks.Add

Dim result
result  = xlObj.Application.Run("Headers.xlsm!Headers",filename)

xlFile.Close True
xlObj.Quit
```

this my vba function

```
Function Headers(filename As String) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim myWb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Dim flag As Boolean
Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename)

Dim arr

arr = Array("col1","col2")

For i = 1 To 2
    If Cells(1, i).Value = arr(i - 1) Then
         Headers = "True"
    Else
         Headers = "False , Not Found Header " & arr(i - 1)
         Exit Function
End If
Next

myWb.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Shouldn't `xlObj.Application.Run` be `xlObj.Run`? `xlObj` is already the application. Did you manage to find out in which line the error occurs? And what is `filename` in your VBScript? it is not defined and empty. • Note that if you `Exit Function` the workbook does not get closed because `myWb.Close` is never reached (it cancels the function immediately at this point of the code). Instead use `Exit For` to just get out of the loop and still close the workbook.

Comment: xlObj.Run file name hardcoded worked , will try with dynamci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your VBScript `xlObj` is set to be an application `Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. That means `xlObj.Application` should be `xlObj` only.
2. In your VBScript `Filename` is not declared nor set to a value therefore it is empty. You need to define value to it.

   ```
   Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set objWorkbook = xlObj.Workbooks.Open("E:\Headers.xlsm")

   xlObj.Visible = False
   xlObj.Workbooks.Add

   Dim Filename 'declare filename and set a value to it
   Filename = "E:\YourPath\Yourfile.xlsx"        

   Dim Result
   Result = xlObj.Run("Headers.xlsm!Headers", Filename)

   xlFile.Close True
   xlObj.Quit
   ```
3. In your function you use `Exit Function`. This will stop the code immediately at this point, which means your workbook `myWb` will not be closed! It stays open because `myWb.Close` is never reached. Change `Exit Function` to `Exit For` to just exit the loop and continue to close the workbook.
4. `Cells(1, i).Value` is neither specified which workbook it is in nor which worksheet. This is not very reliable never call `Cells` or `Range` without specifying workbook and worksheet (or Excel will guess which one you mean, and Excel can fail if you are not precise).

   Therfore I recommend to use something like `myWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value` if you always mean the first worsheet in that workbook. Alternatively if it has a defined name using its name would be more reliable: `myWb.Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(1, i).Value`
5. If you turn off `ScreenUpdating` don't forget to turn it on in the end.
6. Error handling in case filename does not exist would be nice to not break the function.
7. You can slightly improve speed by assuming `Headers = "True"` as default and just turn it `False` in case you find any non matching header. This way the variable is only set once to `True` instead of multiple times for every correct header.

   ```
   Public Function Headers(ByVal Filename As String) As String    
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       Dim flag As Boolean 'flag is never used! you can remove it

       On Error Resume Next 'error handling here would be nice to not break if filename does not exist.
       Dim myWb As Workbook
       Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filename) 
       On Error Goro 0 'always reactivate error reporting after Resume Next!!!

       If Not myWb Is Nothing Then            
           Dim Arr() As Variant
           Arr = Array("col1", "col2")

           Headers = "True" 'assume True as default and just change it to False if a non matching header was found (faster because variable is only set true once instead for every column).
           Dim i As Long 'better use Long since there is no benefit in using Integer
           For i = 1 To UBound(arr) + 1 'use `ubound to find the upper index of the array, so if you add col3 you don't need to change the loop boundings
               If Not myWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = Arr(i - 1) Then 'define workbook and worksheet for cells
                    Headers = "False , Not Found Header " & Arr(i - 1)
                    Exit For '<-- just exit loop but still close the workbook
               End If
           Next i
       Else
           Headers = "File '" & Filename & "' not found!"
       End If

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       myWb.Close
   End Function
   ```